# Django CMS CSS trouble?

Tags: html, css, django, styles, django-cms

Im trying to style a plugin in my Django-CMS project ( django 1.11, CMS 3.6.0 ).

Im trying to add my class to my plugin html, like this :

```
<div class="question">
    <h1 class="question-title">{{ instance.poll.question }}</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' instance.poll.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {% for choice in instance.poll.choice_set.all %}
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="{{ choice.id }}">
                    {{ choice.choice_text }}
                </label>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Then I go into my css, and try to apply some styles to the plugin, but nothing happens. When I inspect my div which should have a class of "question" in the browser, there is no class even though I specified it in my html. Why is that ?

When I do something like :

```
body {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

It applies the styles correctly.

Anybody knows what is happening here ? Where are my custom classes from the html ?

I was trying to find a guide on Django-CMS and styling, but Im not having much luck.

Thank you guys !

Comment: did you load static files ?